# increase memory in phpstorm 9.0.2

Tags: ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

How can I increase the memory of my phpstorm and what value should I put,so that it will make faster.

here is my

phpstorm.exe.vmoptions

```
    -server
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=250m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=150m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: I'd suggest to try 64-bit PhpStorm first (you will have to install 64bit JDK for that)

Comment: @LazyOne  but my o.s is 32 bit can I still install phpstorm with 64 in 32 bit operation system?

Comment: @LazyOne, how can I run phpstorm in 64 bit mode ?

Comment: No -- you cannot run x64 apps on 32-bit OS. These days almost all computers (if it's Windows, in particular) come with x64 bit OS .. so I thought it would be the case here as well...

Comment: See if you will find anything useful here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827537-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties

Comment: But in general -- try increasing `-Xmx` option. Keep in mind that more memory does not necessarily makes it faster because more memory in Java means slower GC (Garbage Collection)...

Comment: Check questions/answers here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[intellij-idea]+increase+memory